Question Regarding the Negation of a Universal Statement in Connexive Logic
In Connexive Logic, would the negation of ∀x(Ax→Bx) be ∃x(Ax→¬Bx)?

The negation should be ∃x(Ax∧¬Bx). Your answer and the original proposition could be simultaneously true, for example, there's no x in the domain satisfying Ax, then both implications are vacuously true...

There are a couple of difficulties in answering this question. One is that connexive logic refers to a family of related logics and in the literature you will find varieties such as strongly connexive, weakly connexive, hyperconnexive, bi-connexive, restrictedly connexive, etc., so there may not be a single answer. The other is that quantified connexive logic has been studied only fairly recently and there is comparatively little published material covering it.
Usually, quantifiers in connexive logic are specified to behave in the same way as quantifiers in classical logic. Under this interpretation we have:
~(∀x)(Fx → Gx)   ⊨   (∃x)~(Fx → Gx)
which differs from the familiar expression in classical logic:
¬(∀x)(Fx ⊃ Gx)  ⊨  (∃x)(Fx ∧ ¬Gx)
But there is a natural way to define a connexive style of quantifier that is contraclassical.  Wansing and Weber show how it is possible to define a quantified connexive logic they call GQQC in which
~(Ax)(Fx → Gx)   ⊨   (Ax)(Fx → ~Gx)
Where ~ is connexive negation, and → is the connexive conditional. These quantifiers are often written using 'blackboard bold' A and E. Since I don't have any way to write this in unicode, I am using regular bold A.
This looks very odd, but we need to bear in mind that connexive conditionals are intended to express a much stronger relationship between the antecedent and consequent of a conditional than the material conditional. A natural way to illustrate the semantics of this is with bare plurals. Suppose someone were to state, "Whales are fish" and we wished to contradict this. If we express this classically using the material conditional we get as the negation: "There is at least one whale that is not a fish". This does not do justice to the example. The negation of, "Whales are fish" is, "Whales are not fish".
This whole field is still relatively new and under development. There are other ways of negating universally quantified connexive expressions.
Heinrich Wansing and Zach Weber, "Quantifiers in connexive logic (in general and in particular)", Logic Journal of the IGPL (2024). Advance copy available here.
Heinrich Wansing and Hitoshi Omori, "Connexive Logic, Connexivity, and Connexivism: Remarks on Terminology", Studia Logica (2023) 112: 1-35.
Nissim Francez, "Connexive Restricted Quantification", Notre Dame Journal of Formal Logic (2020) 61 (3): 383-402.
